# remote access to IIS website

Tags: hosting, asp.net, iis

I hosted my website on IIS 5.1 and i can access it on the local network but i cant seem to access it outside of the network.  It gave me a page sayin it cannot be display.  I have port forward it to port 80, and turn off the routers firewall.  In the IIS manager i chose the ip-address to be my local ip-adress.  I even talk to ppl for my ISP and they dont have the port block.  I added port 80 to my firewall exceptions, allow anonymous user. what else am i missing??  Ive tried connecting my laptop directly to the router and doesnt work. i went to whatismyip.com to get the external ip-address then type that in the URL box, even tried putting a /virtualdirectory after the ip-address, doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You mention a router and external IP address, so it sounds like you're using NAT routing in your setup.  If this is the case, ensure that NAT port forwarding is enabled in the NAT configuration on the router.  This will take incoming requests from the WAN side on port 80 and forward them to the private, internal IP address on the LAN side of the router.  The web server should then be configured to accept requests on port 80 on the private, internal IP address.

When accessing the site from inside the network, use the private internal IP address.  When accessing from outside, use the external public IP address.